# How to Authenticate users through an organization? (Auth0)

Tags: authentication, oauth-2.0, oauth, jwt, authorization

I understand I need to append the claim in the token to be able to receive org_id.
Question is - should I append it to the ID token or Access token? in the auth0 docs it is appended to both - https://auth0.com/docs/manage-users/organizations/using-tokens#authenticate-users-through-an-organization

Then next question is, how do I actually append it to the token(s)? I have created the organisation, enabled required settings, added roles and permissions through the dashboard, yet I think the last bit what is missing is to create a custom action I assume ?

any ideas?

I tried this example but no luck - https://community.auth0.com/t/how-to-add-roles-and-permissions-to-the-id-token-using-actions/84506

Answer (score 0):

I think you may have misread the auth0 documentation. It's not that you have to append org_id to the token. Instead you need to pass org_id as a query parameter when you redirect the user to authorize (which hit's auth0's `/authorize` endpoint). So your request would look something like this:

```
https://{yourDomain}/authorize?
    response_type=code&
    client_id={yourClientId}&
    redirect_uri={https://yourApp/callback}&
    scope={scope}&
    state={state}&
    organization={yourOrganizationId}
```

When you authenticate with an organization auth0 will add it to the token for you.